# Hosting asp.net application with my custom domain name, in my own machine

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have some asp.net applications which are already hosted with a hosting provider, with my registered domain names.
Now I want to try to host the applications in my own machine. I know that if I host in own machine, the machine needs to be always on, internet need to be always up, but still I want to try that.
My question is how I can host multiple asp.net application, with different domain name, in my own machine.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can.You shouldn't but you can. As long as you have a fixed IP.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to do it? Can you please share reference for this? I have fixed IP.

Comment: Someone please reply.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved.

1. I had created a virtual machine in Azure, which has a public IP address. Added Inbound Port Rule for 80 and 443 port.
2. I have several domain names. I went to DNS Management page in the domain provider's website. Added two "A" type records in [DNS Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBoNQ.png), with "Host Name" as "www" and "@", and with the public IP Address.
3. Added Websites in IIS with Port 80 (for http) and Port 443 (for https) and Host Name with corresponding domain name on [Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeRZN.png) for each application. Note, you can add multiple websites with same port, if the Host Name is different.

Now I am able to access each application with domain name on internet.